# Why does `compress` behave differently depending on file types?

Tags: command-line

`compress 1.pdf` does not compress the file to 1.pdf.Z. But `compress 1.sh` compress the file to `1.sh.Z`. (compress is `/usr/bin/compress` on macOS.) Does anybody know why is it so? How to make it compresses files regardless of file types?

Answer (score 4):

From the man page:

> If compression would not reduce the size of a file, the file is ignored.

Compress is using a very simple compression algorithm and for some files (like PDFs which are already using a compression), the algorithm is not able to reduce the file size. In this case, the result would actually be *bigger*. In this case, `compress` is simply leaving the file as-is.

Pass the `-f` flag if you do want to "compress" the file even if it would become bigger. From the man page:

> -f             Files are overwritten without prompting for confirmation.  Also, for compress, files are compressed even if they are not actually reduced in size.

Since `compress`'s algorithm isn't very good, I would recommend using a better compressor like `bzip2` or `xz` if you're able to.